# why first text field auto selected in java fx

Tags: javafx

i want to initialize text in java fx text field. why the text is already selected.
[image]

code snippets in class FXMLDocumentController

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        source.setText("test source");
        dest.setText("test dest");
        source.setEditable(false);
        dest.setEditable(false);
    }
```

Comment: yes @fabian i mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default behavior of a `TextField` on gaining focus by means other than mouse interaction. If you want to change that, you could add a listener to the `focused` property that undoes the selection:

```
source.focusedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            int carretPosition = source.getCaretPosition();
            if (source.getAnchor() != carretPosition) {
                source.selectRange(carretPosition, carretPosition);
            }
        });
    }
});
```